# Setting values from the UI for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to set values of integers from the UI and have it set to javascript. Basically I'm working with a C3 chart, I'm using the max and min functions. I would like to have a user change those values from the UI and in turn change the value of the javascript. Here is the function that sets the y axis of the chart:

## Function:

```
$(function(){
  instance.axis.max();
});
```

You can basically set the value as the parameter of max. This works as I intend it to but how can I make it dynamic from the UI. Right now I have this text field setup that I would like to wire up to change the max value here is the text field

## HTML text field:

```
<div class="y-axis">
  <input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />
</div>
```

Is there a way I can set a data attribute to the html and have it set to the javascript?

Comment: So when the user put a value in that input, you want to get that value and use it as a parameter to the max function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using JQuery. So, you can do this as below

```
$(function(){
  var number = $("#replyNumber").attr('min');
  //if this is not number then convert it into number.
  // number = Number(number);
  instance.axis.max(number);
});
```

Comment: I think that the min attribute is just an attribute used by html5 when using input of type number http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp